# HTML5 input URL validation for Edge and Safari

Tags: html, safari, cross-browser, microsoft-edge, url-validation

I'm trying to ensure that the user inputs a correct URL within

```
<input type='url' >
```

however have tested a few erroneous test entries that seem to pass as URL only on Edge (40.15063.0.0) and Safari (5.1.7).

e.g:

http://

https://

These tests are prompted "please enter a url" in Chrome and Firefox.
How do I improve input type='url' to not accept entries such as this in Edge and Safari?

You can test type url here:
https://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/3-url.html

Comment: Not the problem but the `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Comment: Edited in regards to your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the pattern attribute to catch the test cases:
http://
https://

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
Homepage: <input type="url" name="website" pattern="https?://.+" 
title="Include http://">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

As shown on the last example on W3schools documentation:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp